# Strange arrangement of columns in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have made the following count table taking the Centers as side break and multiple different columns as top break. I'm unable to understand why a specific value from a column comes at last row in dataframe. Is it some way the data is sorted by the dataframe.Is there a way to stop this default sorting
Below is my code:

```
cols=['Gender','QAge_Post','SEC']
q2=(nb.melt(id_vars='Center_Name',value_vars=cols)
   .groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Center_Name'),'variable','value'])
   .size()
   .unstack(level=[1,2],fill_value=0))
q2.to_excel('Basic.xlsx')
q2.insert(0, 'Total', q2['Gender'].sum(axis=1))
```

The output is as follows
[image]

I want column 56-65 years along with the other age parameters, i.e after column 46-55 years. Many thanks

Comment: please add code to generate your original dataframe so that others can reproduce the issue.

Comment: `nb=pd.read_excel('consumer.xlsx',sheet_name='Labelled')` Just a normal read excel to dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first idea is sorting `MultiIndex`.

```
q2=(nb.melt(id_vars='Center_Name', value_vars=cols)
   .groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Center_Name'), 'variable', 'value'])
   .size()
   .unstack(level=[1, 2], fill_value=0)
   .sort_index(axis=1))
```

If the problem still persists, maybe some whitespace, best check converted columns to tuples.

```
q2=(nb.melt(id_vars='Center_Name', value_vars=cols)
   .groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Center_Name'), 'variable', 'value'])
   .size()
   .unstack(level=[1, 2], fill_value=0))

print(q2.columns.tolist())
```

Comment: Your first code worked fine. Thanks. But can you explain what was the issue and on what basis the sorting is happening on axis 1

Comment: @BenjaminRoy - I guess no sorting ;)